# How to slow down an object?

Tags: animation

My object is following X and Y axis. Now I want to slow it down at the end. Normally, I can do this in the Graph Editor. I use Linear lines and when I change it to Bezier, my object doesn't follow the direction correctly. It looks drunken. I guess I have to change X and Y to exactly the same value but that's not easy. Does anyone know another method to slow down my object at the end of the animation?

[Here's the blend file](https://shorturl.at/tBIJ2)

Comment: in the Graph Editor you can change only one vertex to bezier if you want and not the entire curve

Comment: tbh i don't understand what you wanna do. How can an object follow x AND y axis!? maybe either provide your blend file or/and provide a sketch what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an action constraint:

unlink the action from the object and assign an action constraint to it, targeting at your X and Y animation.

Create a controller object, generally an empty or a bone, and set it as target of the constraint, choosing one transform channel to drive the action (in my example X loc).

Trim the duration of both the triggered action and the target transform.

Now you have a single graph editor curve that controls the whole complex action.

[image]

Comment: +1 for understanding (hopefully) what he wants...i didn't get it.

Comment: Good tip. I added an empty object on my ball and added an object constaint action. But, my ball shrinked and the position is wrong. When I changed the Target Local Space to Customer Space, the size is ok but guess...it does not work anymore. See my image: shorturl.at/hizAU Do you have a tip again?

Comment: Hard to tell, maybe you can upload a simplified version of the file (just the 8-ball, the empty and a plane).

Comment: @joshsanfelici you can download the filter shorturl.at/tBIJ2 (~650MB)

Comment: As action constraint is adding motion to existing, you have to reset its loc rot and scale (000, 000, 111), turn off the action in the action editor and turn off the rigid body behaviour, so that the only controller is the action constraint.

Comment: Many, many thanks Josh. It works now perfect. :)